# QTabWidget tabs on the vertical, but text in horizontal

Tags: c++, qt, cross-platform, sidebar, qtabwidget

I'm trying to make an app in C++ Qt with a sidebar like this one:

[image: Finder's sidebar]

But when making QTabWidget's orientation to West, it makes the text vertical. How to have the text on the left, but horizontally-aligned? Ps: I don't need icons. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [QListWidget](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qlistwidget.html) to show the "tabs" (with some mods to make it look like you want) and [QStackedWidget](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qstackedwidget.html) to handle switching between pages like normal tab widget does.

Comment: I did tried the QListWidget approach, but how do I make it look like that? Stylesheets? I don't see as much customizing power there...

Comment: If you don't need icons, what do you need to customize? Remove borders and change background and make a highlight gradient? That should be doable with stylesheets.

Comment: I solved it with the following stylesheet: http://pastebin.com/6UqpixtQ, many thanks to you!

Comment: Is the solution available somewhere else? pastebin has removed it , as it it is too old now.

Comment: it would be nice to get stylesheet from somewhere??

Answer (score 3):

A bit of "advertising" for a [WTFPL](http://www.wtfpl.net/) implementation [here on assembla](https://www.assembla.com/code/extendedtabwidget/subversion/nodes)
Any contribution will be much appreciated.

[image: exemple1]
[image: exemple2]
[image: exemple3]

Answer (score 1):

use QProxyStyle, this function will rotate 180 for text, and you can rotate 90。

```
void MyProxyStyle::drawItemText( QPainter* painter,
                                 const QRect&,
                                 int alignment,
                                 const QPalette& palette,
                                 bool enabled,
                                 const QString& text,
                                 QPalette::ColorRole textRole ) const
{
    painter->save();
    painter->translate(160,50);
    painter->rotate(-180);

    QCommonStyle::drawItemText( painter,
                                rectangle,
                                alignment,
                                palette,
                                enabled,
                                text,
                                textRole );

    painter->restore();
}
```